# Convert terminal tables into csv or json

Tags: csv, json, snap, flatpak

Does a tool exist to convert tables on the command line like `snap list` or `flatpak list` into csv or json ouput.

I imagine it like this: `<name> "snap list" --csv`

Comment: Because I have neither snap nor flatpak installed, I can't develop this answer more fully, so I'll just suggest looking into [the column command](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/column.1.html). I **think** this will approximate what you want.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Since these tables take very different shapes, the tool you are looking for would need to have an understanding of the tables of each program you might use.

You shouldn't try to parse nice tabular output - that's for human consumption, not computer consumption. Most programs that can output some pretty tables also have an option where they output the data in a nicely defined format (such as JSON, for example), which then can be converted unambiguously.